# Maximum Modulus Theorem for Unbounded Domain

Tags: complex-analysis

**Theorem: Maximum Modulus Theorem for Unbounded Domain**

Suppose $D$ is an unbounded domain and $f\in A(D)$. If $f$ is bounded on $D$ and $|f(s)|\leq M$ for any $s\in \partial D$, then $|f(z)|\leq M$ for any $z\in D$.

**Problem**

Let $D=\{z\in \mathbb{C}: x>0, -\frac{\pi}{2}<y<\frac{\pi}{2}\}$ and $f\in A(D)$. Suppose $|f|\le 1$ in $\partial D $ and for some $A>0$, $$|f(z)|\leq e^{|z|^A} \ \text{in} \ D,$$ prove that $|f|\leq1$ in $D$.

**My Solution**
By the theorem

*D is unbounded, *$f\in A(D)$, *$f$ is bounded on the boundary of D

However, I do have a doubt if $f$ is bounded on $D$. Since, $|f(z)|\leq e^{|z|^A} $, can I directly say that $f$ is bounded? I have a doubt because as $|z|\rightarrow \infty$, $e^{|z|^A}$ also approaches infinity.

Do you have any idea? Thank you.

Comment: I am assuming that I can use the theorem in the given problem.

Comment: _Is_ $A(D)$ the space of functions continuous on the closure of $D$ and holomorphic in $D$? And is $\infty$ included as a point of $\overline D$ and $\partial D$?

Comment: First question, yes. Second question, just base on the given $D$.

Comment: Sorry, I don't see how "just base on the given $D$" tells me whether we're including $\infty$ in $\overline D$ and $\partial D$...

Comment: Base on the given $D$, $|z|$ can approach to $\infty$ on the closure and on the boundary of $D$.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question! The answer is "yes" or "no": Is $\infty\in\overline D$ and is $\infty\in\partial D$?

Comment: Consider $g(z) = \exp (\exp (z) - 1)$. This is an entire function and $\lvert g(z)\rvert \leqslant 1$ on $\partial D$. But $g$ is not bounded on $D$. The growth restriction is essential for the conclusion.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich. Sorry, I just can't figure out why $\infty$ became a point of $D$. Are you referring to $\mathbb{C}\cup \{\infty\}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you certainly cannot assume $f$ is bounded.

This is a Phragmen-Lindelof sort of theorem. The plan is roughly this: Find a family of functions $g_\epsilon$ such that $g_\epsilon f$ is bounded and $|g_\epsilon|\le 1$ on the boundary, also $g_\epsilon\to1$ pointwise in the interior as $\epsilon\to0$. Deduce from the theorem that $|fg_\epsilon|\le  1$ in the interior and then let $\epsilon\to0$ to get $|f|\le 1$.

Comment: oh. Thank you @David. You're right about Phragmen-Lindelof Theorem. Does it mean that I have to use the Lemma prior to the Theorem given above?